# var and let in nodejs

Tags: node.js, var, fibonacci, let

Recently in HackerRank I came through the Node.js question:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, …
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

The solution I wrote on HackerRank doesn't pass testcase:

```js
function fib() {
  var sum = 2;
  var a = 1;
  var b = 2;
  var n = 0;
  while (n < 4000000) {
    n = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = n;
    if (n % 2 === 0) {
      sum = sum + n;
    }
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
fib();
```

when I replaced `var` with `let` the test case passed. Is it something wrong with the HackerRank platform or with the `var` keyword? I had a weird experience in past while passing test cases on HackerRank, same code fails and pass.

Comment: Why did the test case fail? Did it time out or did it get the wrong result?

Comment: the problem is I can't see why it fails.